# In small sites, what about showing "top 3" or "top X" for best users in a given period instead of "top XX%"?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-leagues

When going through the profiles of the top users you can find things like:

> [image]

And the same occurs for [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) (ranked #2), [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) (#3) and all the way until [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) (#46): they all get a text "top 0.01% overall". This is not bad per-se, so we get a good vision of someone being among the best users.

However, in small sites, the top user from all time gets a "top 0.28% overall":

> [image]

This does not give much information as a number, and rarely makes us think that it is the person with the more reputation overall.

For this, I suggest changing the text to something more meaningful for top users like:

> **top #1 user overall**

We could argue that the site is not about competition itself. However, the fact that we have such rankings, as well as tag top users, makes me think that such change will give better content than what those "top XX% overall" are currently giving.

Comment: Also adding a gold, silver, or bronze medal would be nice.

Comment: Why just small sites?

Comment: @PatrickHofman well, at least in those because in big ones the percentage shows a number that is relevant enough (0.01% and things like that), while in smaller ones the number is just not giving any value.